# Angular 2 RC5 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot resolve component using 'HomeComponent'

Tags: angular, typescript

i am trying my routing feature of abgular2 RC5, Please have look at below code.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component,HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
<h1>My First Angular 2 App </h1>  
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
`
})
export class AppComponent {}

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

**usercomp.ts**

```
@Component({
selector: 'user-comp',
template: `    
<h1>USER COMPONENT</h1>
`
})
export class UserComponent {}
```

**homecomponent.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'home-component',
template: `
<h1>Home Component</h1>
`
})
export class HomeComponent {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
 import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
 import { routing } from './approuter'
 import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router'
 import { HomeComponent } from './homecomponent'
 import { UserComponent } from './usercomp'

 @NgModule({
   imports:      [ BrowserModule,routing ],
   declarations: [ AppComponent,HomeComponent,UserComponent ],
   bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
  })
 export class AppModule { }
```

**approuter.ts**

```
   import { RouterModule,Routes } from '@angular/router'

  const APP_ROUTES:Routes = [
    {
    path:'user',
    component:'UserComponent'
   },
   {
    path:'',
    component:'HomeComponent'
   }

   ];

    export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

***ERROR***

[image]

I tried exporting  HomeComponent and UserComponent home component  everywhere but unable to get rid of this code. With RC4 it worked fine the older way but not sure what wrong i did here, please have a look and let me know when i have mistaken..

Comment: please provide implementation for approuter

Comment: could you add `approuter.ts`?

Comment: sorry my bad updated..

Comment: @Nomad its just the same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246750/angular2-rc5-and-electron-error-cannot-resolve-component-using/39246891#39246891)

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar i did pretty good google search though before posting this question, not sure why this one didnt show up..

Comment: @Nomad no problem, that happens :) though cheers, you find a solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   import { RouterModule,Routes } from '@angular/router'
   import { HomeComponent } from './homecomponent';
   import { UserComponent } from './usercomp';

   const APP_ROUTES:Routes = [
       {
           path:'user',
           component: UserComponent
       },
       {
           path:'',
           component: HomeComponent
       }
   ];

    export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

component accepts any component type, check class reference [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Routes-type-alias.html)

Comment: Okay, did you tried changing your approuter.ts file with above code provided by me?, you are not supposed to give a string for component property as you did in your implementation, you need to give it a component type. Copy paste my code over your code in approuter.ts file

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add pathMatch to your default route:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'  },
{ path: 'home',  loadChildren: './app/home/home.module#HomeModule' }
```